# openID connect without resource owner authorization

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

the use case I have is, there are multiple systems that access each other over the internet, all sharing the same user base. openId connect seems to be the way of identity management. this means every system would need user/ resource owner authorization to access the users' resources on other systems. But I'd like to skip the user authorization for every system to access other systems. can openId connect work with client credentials flow instead of authorization flow? is the design even good enough?

would like to know the standard security protocol for the same

Comment: What do you mean, that you would like to skip user authorization? You do not want user to provide credentials every time user is accessing new application (system)?

Comment: For service-to-service calls, [oAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer grant type](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7523) is a good option, e.g. see [Google's implementation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). OpenID Connect (OIDC) is a superset of oAuth and the new stuff in OIDC is specifically for authentication of (usually human) users.

Comment: @BartoszRosa yes, i do not want user to authorize every time he/she is accessing a new system. all the systems are part of the same application. but i would want controlled authorization between systems. certain api's of the system must be accessible only to a few systems